# How to add on change listener to a list (not list view)

Tags: android, list

How can i add a on change listener to my list (not list view)?

for example i need some Thing like:

```
List<c> C;
C_SQLiteData data;

.
.
.
.
C = data.findall();
C.addonchangelistener(new onchangelistener){
            @Override
            public void onChange(View arg0) {
                refreshlistview(view);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529273/how-to-add-listener-on-arraylist-in-java

Answer (score 0):

you can use intent to refresh the list after performing changes like this

```
Dochanges();
Intent refresh=new Intent("com.example.Project.Same_activity");
startActivity(refresh);
```