# custom arraylist with notification for delete and add

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to detect when adding some items to the array list or when removing some item from it. Actually I have some code like below:

```
public class myClass {

    MyCustomArrayList<MyObject> al;

    public void method1() {

        al.add(myObject);        
        // Do other works
        al.remove(myObject)
        // Do other works
    }

    private void DoByEachAdd() {
        //I want array list call this method by adding each item to it.
        // It should be in this class because it is doing some works
        // related to this class. for example changing some private variables
    }

    private void DoByEachRemove() {
        // I want array list call this method by adding each item to it.
        // It should be in this class too.
    }

}
```

I know that array list has not the ability for having listener or some kind of notifications or events and if I want to detect add should have a custom array list. something like below class:

```
class MyArrayList<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> list;

    public MyList(){
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    }
    public void add(T t) {
        list.add(t) {
        //do other things you want to do when items are added 
    }
    public T remove(T t) {
        list.remove(t);
        //do other things you want to do when items are removed
}
```

(I get it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529462/1939409))

So the question is that: how can I inform the object of `MyArrayList` (`al`) that call `DoByEachAdd` and `DoByEachRemove` methods when the `remove` and `add` method fired. Does some body have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First, follow naming convention. Second, the three class names you used for the same class, `MyList`, `MyArrayList` and `MyCustomArrayList` will confuse people. As for your question, you would have to have an instance field inside `MyArrayList` of type `myClass` (unless you want to refactor `DoByEachAdd` and `DoByEachRemove` to be `static`). This can be done by adding it as a constructor parameter, e.g.

```
// inside MyArrayList
private ArrayList<T> list;
private final myClass instance;

public MyArrayList(myClass instance) { // <-- NOT MyList
    list = new ArrayList();
    this.myClass = myClass;
}
```

Also, I question your approach. Other classes with instances of `MyArrayList` can only use the `add` and `remove` methods of `ArrayList`. If you want to save a lot of bother and have all methods visible, either declare `list` as `public final` or make `MyArrayList` a subclass of `ArrayList`, e.g.

```
public class MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    private final myClass instance;

    public MyArrayList(myClass instance) { // <-- NOT MyList
        list = new ArrayList();
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        boolean returnThis = super.add(t);
        // do some stuff
        instance.DoByEachAdd();
        return returnThis;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(T t) {
        boolean returnThis = super.remove(t);
        // do some stuff
        instance.DoByEachRemove();
        return returnThis;
    }
}
```

If you insist on being able to  return a `T` from `remove`, declare another method:

```
public T removeT(T t) {
    remove(t);
    // do some stuff
    return someT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give access to your `myClass` to `MyArrayList`

```
class MyArrayList<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> list;
    private myClass theClass;

public MyList(myClass theClass){
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    this.theClass = theClass;
...
}
public void add(T t) {
    list.add(t) {
    //do other things you want to do when items are added 
    theClass.DoByEachAdd();
}
public T remove(T t) {
    list.remove(t);
    //do other things you want to do when items are removed
    theClass.DoByEachRemove
}
```

and in your `myClass` give the object to your list

```
public class myClass {

   MyCustomArrayList<MyObject> al;


 public myClass(){

  al = new MyCustomArrayList<MyObject>(this);

 }
public void method1() {

    al.add(myObject);        
    // Do other works
    al.remove(myObject)
    // Do other works
}

public void DoByEachAdd() {
    //I want array list call this method by adding each item to it.
    // It should be in this class because it is doing some works
    // related to this class. for example changing some private variables
}

public void DoByEachRemove() {
    // I want array list call this method by adding each item to it.
    // It should be in this class too.
}

}
```