# Sharing an ArrayList between two threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency

So I have two threads running where one of them is supposed to get information from the user and the other thread is suppose to work with information supplied by users as follows:

```
public class UserRequest implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String request;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter request:");
        request = input.nextLine();
        try
        {
            //do something
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And second thread:

```
public class Poller implements Runnable {

ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();

public void poll()
{
    for(String color : colors)
    {
        if(color == "")
        {
            //do work
        }
        else
        {
            //do work
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    colors.add("Violet");
    colors.add("Green");
    colors.add("Yellow");
    colors.add("Orange");

    while(true)
        poll();     
}
}
```

What I would like to do is take whatever input the user entered inside the `UserRequest` object and push into the `ArrayList` in `Poller` object so it can "work" on the new value as well. I have looked at some thing like `BlockingQueue` but I don't want either Thread to wait for the other since they have other tasks they need to accomplish in addition to this sharing of data. How can I go about doing this ?

Comment: ArrayList is not thread-safe.

Comment: What could be a thread-safe alternative and how would I share it between the threads ?

Comment: As many have pointed out, a queue is probably what you are looking for. You can use the ConcurrentLinkedQueue for something that's thread-safe without excessive locking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've used the verb 'push' and 'poll', it seems you are looking for a `Queue` not a `List`.

Therefore, I think you're looking for the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).

It allows you to have your `UserRequest` objects feed it and your `Poller` objects to consume it.

Though it seems your `Poller` objects will have quite a high CPU consuption because of the open `while` not having any `wait`:

```
public class Poller implements Runnable {
  Queue<String> colors = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();

  public void poll() {
    while(this.colors.isEmpty()){
      Thread.currentThread().wait();
    }

    String color = this.colors.poll();

    while(color != null) {
      if(color == "") {
        //do work

      } else {
        //do work
      }

      color = this.colors.poll();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    colors.offer("Violet");
    colors.offer("Green");
    colors.offer("Yellow");
    colors.offer("Orange");

    while(true) {

      this.poll();
    }
  }
}
```

**this code needs some changes to run** but it contains pretty much everything you need.
What it does is very simple: It keeps polling until there are no elements left.
Once that happens, the `Poller` object asks it's current `Thread` to sleep, since there's no point for it to run without elements in the `Queue`.

```
public class UserRequest implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    String request;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true) {
      System.out.println("Please enter request:");
      request = input.nextLine();

      try {
        //do something

      } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

      } finally {
        this.notifyAll(); // Notifies all sleeping threads to wake up
      }
    }
  }
```

If you notice, I've only added a `notifyAll` call to your `UserRequest` class. Why? Very simple: `notifyAll` wakes all `wait`ing `Thread`s which is exactly what all `Poller`s without elements are doing.

Once it's called, the `Poller`s will wake, check if their color `Queue` has elements and work with them. If the `Queue` has no elements, they will sleep again until a `UserRequest` wakes them up again and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1) It's using `thread safe collection`, like `ConccurentLinkedQueue` for logic with producer-consumer, jobs consuming or etc. If you want to use the class that implements `List interface` (and as a consequence you can take methods same to usual `ArrayList`), you must look to the side of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, but note that this class uses blocking synchronization.

2) Another approach is using built-in java synchronization tools, for example

- [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)
- [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)
- [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)
- [Locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)
- [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html)
- Usual `wait/notify` mechanism

For more details, you must read the specification. Let's consider an example of using Semaphore:

```
private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2, true);

   public void appendToList() throws InterruptedException {
     available.acquire();
     arrayList.add(.....); //put here what u need
   }

   public void putItem(Object x) {
     if (someLogicHere(x)) //semaphore releases counter in this place
       available.release();
   }
```

Of course, you can combine usage all of them, e.g. you can use a few `semaphores` simultaneously, or use diff tools.

Answer (score 1):

"but I don't want either Thread to wait for the other since they have other tasks they need to accomplish in addition to this sharing of data."

There's no way to accomplish this. Any proper threading of the class will *always* suffer from the problem that you will need to have one thread wait while the other does something. The point though is you want to minimize that. You want to only cause the thread to stall very briefly and rarely and only in those cases where not doing so will cause it to fault. You can use one of the synchronized data structures or you can just write a little bit of synchronization code yourself.

The only object in question is the arraylist, and you want the absolute minimum amount of stall on either thread. So you would want to synchronize it based on the object of the arraylist itself. So just write a couple little synchronization blocks around the points where you access the arraylist object.

```
public class Poller implements Runnable {

    ArrayList<String> colors;

    public Poller(ArrayList<String> colors) {
        this.colors = colors;
        //pass in colors object, if modified from the scanner side it must synchronize the block around the colors object too.
    }

    public void doWork(String color) {
        //do work
    }

    public void addColor(String color) {
        synchronized (colors) {
            colors.add(color);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.interrupted())
            if (!colors.isEmpty()) {
                String color;
                synchronized (colors) {
                    color = colors.remove(0);
                }
                doWork(color); //work done outside synch
            }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The point is just never be removing or adding things to the list at the same time. You cannot loop over the list as a whole because if the work is done in-loop it's a problem and the size of the array might change so you don't know how bit it is. But, you can use an ArrayList for this, just synchronize the blocks of code where you change the datastructure and get the string out of that synchronized block and then do work on it. This way the *only* stall is the brief instant one thread is reading or writing and the other one needs to. Both of which are very fast operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access new value entered by the user from poller object then:

- As objects are stored in heap , instead of creating a *new instance* of arrayList in the Poller class you could just send a reference of list object from the UserRequest.So that when yu change add new value to arrayList in userRequest it will be reflected in arrayList being used by Poller.

For Example, You can do it this way:

```
 public class UserRequest implements Runnable {

private ArrayList<String> arrayList  = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String request;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter request:");
        request = input.nextLine();
        try
        {

         Poller poller = new Poller(arrayList);
         Thread t = new Thread(poller);
         t.start();

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

You can change your Poller class like this:

```
 public class Poller implements Runnable {
  private ArrayList arrayList = null;    

  Poller(ArrayList<String> arrayList){
     this.arrayList = arrayList; 
   }

public void poll()
{
    for(String color : arrayList)
    {
        if(color == "")
        {
            //do work
        }
        else
        {
            //do work
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

       while(true){
        poll();   
     }    
}
```

But instead of calling pool in a infinity loop you should add a listener to your arrayList so that you call `poll()`  only when a new value has been added to the List.

You can check out this link to know more about adding listener to a `ArrayList`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529462/7083385

Comment: Using `ArrayList`s in a multi-thread environment can cause the `ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown since you cannot guarantee the writing and reading order.

Comment: Yea but @Jenna wants to do it using ArrayList

Comment: The OP also gave the option of a  `BlockingQueue` which fixes the concurrency but blocks the user input until a `Poller` consumes it.

Comment: You can also get `ConcurrentModificationException` while try to remove objects of a `arrayList`  while looping

Comment: I dont think theres any other way if OP wants to do it in using arrayList

Comment: Yes @MR.JOIS, any change to the `ArrayList` while in use will cause the exception to be thrown as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Comment: If the OP really wants to use `ArrayList`s, there's gonna be a whole lot of `synchronize` blocks.

Comment: What I want to say is, in this scenario, `List`s are not the best tools for the job because they are being read concurrently. If you were populating the `List` fully and only then sending them to be used, they I would agree. However, the way it's being asked I think `Queue`s are better because they guarantee an order for the parsing of the elements, normally in FIFO mode, which `List`s won`t.

Comment: That I agree with you! I only used arrayList because OP asked on how we CAN do it with arraylist so chill :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a queue. A queue has its own poll method. You could make it static but i doubt that is the best approach. Generally I use spring to instantiate the queue in some kind of wrapper class but it doesnt look like you are taking that route.

Comment: I agree that making the `Queue` static is not the best approach. The OP hasn't said anything about `spring` either and even so, injection wouldn't solve the problem because you still have to know what you're injecting.