# How do I listen to an ArrayList's size and bind a view to it

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have an ArrayList that is initially empty that the user can populate and remove items from. I have a LinearLayout `toolbar` whose color should be grey when the ArrayList is empty and blue when the ArrayList's size is at least one. Is there some sort of listener that detects changes in ArrayList?

Note: The ArrayList's contents are displayed in a RecyclerView.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578308/add-listener-to-arraylist

Comment: Is the ArrayList used in a ListView or RecyclerView? If so, you can use the View to update the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Code-Apprentice's comment, I can use the RecyclerView to update the toolbar. I used the `addOnLayoutChangeListener`.